# C reading values from a binary file and then print them

Tags: c

I have this code, and want that the program reads/loads the data that is on the file and them printed them, but this didn´t work.

I can´t write on the file, but can´t read it.

I want that when the program initialize, he already have loaded the info that is in the the binary file, so the user can use it, for example for searching people.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define MAX_PERSON 3
#define FILENAME "person.bin"

typedef struct { 
    int id;
    char fname[20],lname[20]; 
}person;

typedef struct { 
    int counter;
    person persons[MAX_PERSON];
}Persons;

int writeStruct(Persons *persons,char *file){
    FILE *outfile; 
       
    outfile = fopen (file, "ab+"); 
    if (outfile == NULL){ 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    printf("\nInsira a informações da pessoa \n");
    printf("Código: ");
    scanf("%d", &persons->persons[persons->counter].id);
    printf("Primeiro Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", persons->persons[persons->counter].fname);
    printf("Último Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", persons->persons[persons->counter].lname);
            
    fwrite (&persons, sizeof(Persons), persons->counter, outfile); 
      
    if(fwrite != 0){  
        puts("Sucess on writing on file");
    }else{
        puts("Error on writing on file");}
  
    fclose (outfile);
    
    return persons->counter++;
}

void loadStruct(Persons *persons,char *file){
    FILE *infile;   

    // Open person.bin for reading 
    infile = fopen(file, "rb+");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read file contents till end of file 
    fread(&persons, sizeof (Persons), persons->counter, infile);
   
    // close file 
    fclose(infile);
}

void listPersons(Persons persons){
    int i;
    
    puts("Lista de pessoas");
    puts("-----------------");
    for(i=0;i < persons.counter; i++) {
        printPerson(persons.persons[i]);
    }
    puts("-----------------");
}

void searchPeople(Persons persons) {
    int number;
    
    printf("Indique o código da pessoa que pretende procurar: ");
    scanf("%d",&number); 
    
    number = searchPerson(persons,number);
    
    if (number != -1) {
        printPerson(persons.persons[number]);
    } else {
        puts(ERROR_PERSON_NOT_EXISTS);
    }
}

int searchPerson(Persons persons,int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < persons.counter; i++) {
        if (persons.persons[i].id == number) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void printPerson(person person){
    printf("%d - %s %s\n", person.id,person.fname, person.lname);
}

int main () 
{   
    int op;
    Persons persons ={.counter = 0};
    
    loadStruct(&persons,FILENAME);
    
    do{
        puts("PESSOAS - BASE DE DADOS");
        puts("-----------------");
        puts("2 - Inserir pessoa");
        puts("3 - Listar pessoas");
        puts("4 - Procurar pessoa");
        puts("0 - Sair");
        puts("-----------------");
        
        printf("Nº Pessoas: %d/%d \n", persons.counter, MAX_PERSON);
        
        printf("Opção:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        printf("\n");
        
        switch (op) {
            case 0:
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                writeStruct(&persons,FILENAME);
                break;
            case 3:
                listPersons(persons);
                break;
            case 4:
                searchPeople(persons);
                break;
            default:
                puts("Opção inválida!");
                break;
        }
        
    }while(op!=0);
}
```

Comment: `persons` is a _pointer_ to, and _not_ an _instance_ of `Persons`. Doing `fread(&persons, sizeof (Persons), persons->counter, infile);` is _wrong_. The buffer passed to `fread` is the address of the _pointer_ and _not_ what the pointer points to. (i.e.) you're trying to read the `struct` into an area that is [only] 4/8 bytes long. You want: `fread(persons, sizeof (Persons), persons->counter, infile);` But, even this will overwrite the `counter` field/member. Is that what you want?

Comment: `if(fwrite != 0)` is not how you test the result of a function call.

Comment: You should assign the result to a variable, then test that variable.

Comment: No i dont want that.
I do what you said and still didn´t work.

Comment: @Barmar you mean doing this ?

 if (fwrite (&persons, sizeof(Persons), persons->counter, outfile) != 0){
        puts("Error on writing on file");
    }else{
         puts("Sucess on writing on file");
    }

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: But see Craig's comment above about the correct first argument to `fread()` and `fwrite()`. It should just be `persons`, not `&persons`.

Comment: @Barmar I did what Craig said but didn´t work.
Besides, the program after loads the file, overwrites the value of the counter.

Comment: When you call `loadStruct`, `persons->counter` is `0`. So `fread(&persons, sizeof (Persons), persons->counter, infile);` will read `0` items.

Comment: Can you add the structure declarations? Is there an array in the `Persons` struct?

Comment: @Barmar yes there are. I already add the structure declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You're just writing one `Persons` structure to the file. You shouldn't use `persons->counter` as the number of items that you're writing or reading, as the array is entirely contained in the structure.

You also shouldn't open the file in append mode. Since you're writing the entire `Persons` structure, not a single `person`, you should open it in write mode and overwrite the whole file.

The first argument to `fwrite()` and `fread()` should be `persons`, not `&persons`, since you want to fill in the structure that it points to, not overwrite the pointer.

To make sure you don't write outside the array, you should check that `persons->counter` hasn't exceeded the size of the array.

```
int writeStruct(Persons *persons,char *file){
    FILE *outfile; 

    if (persons->counter >= MAX_PERSON) {
        puts("File is full\n");
        return persons->counter;
    }

    outfile = fopen (file, "wb"); 
    if (outfile == NULL){ 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    printf("\nInsira a informações da pessoa \n");
    printf("Código: ");
    scanf("%d", &persons->persons[persons->counter].id);
    printf("Primeiro Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", persons->persons[persons->counter].fname);
    printf("Último Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", persons->persons[persons->counter].lname);
            
    fwrite (persons, sizeof(Persons), 1, outfile); 
      
    if(fwrite == 1){  
        puts("Success on writing on file\n");
    }else{
        puts("Error on writing on file\n");
    }
  
    fclose (outfile);
    
    return persons->counter++;
}

void loadStruct(Persons *persons,char *file){
    FILE *infile;

    // Open person.bin for reading 
    infile = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read file contents till end of file 
    fread(persons, sizeof (Persons), 1, infile);
   
    // close file 
    fclose(infile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the third argument of the fwrite shouldn´t be persons->counter, because the way you did it only write one value, one person

Comment: No, this doesn't write one person, it writes the entire `Persons` structure, which contains 3 `person` structures in the array.

Comment: But the code that you post, the program only write, one and the first person.

Comment: No it doesn't. You're confusing `person` with `Persons`.

Comment: `person` is one person. `Persons` contains an array with all the persons.

Comment: @Barman Maybe I´m confusing, and not undestanding very well, but when I load the bin file, the counter decrease, only have one person. 
I want to write the person one by one in the array that is in the struct Persons, not the all struct.

Comment: Why would the counter decrease? You're writing the counter to the file as part of the `Person` structure.

Comment: Maybe I´m, but now I don´t even can write in the file with the code that you post.